# A bullet is shot into the sky, what is its speed when it lands?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

During Cinco de Mayo, you shoot a bullet straight up into the sky at the speed of 500 m/s. The altitude of the bullet $y(t)$ at time $t$ seconds after being shot satisfies the differential equation $y''=-g$.  What is the velocity of the bullet as it hits the ground?

The answer is $-500$ m/s.  I can't figure this out.  My attempt consists of taking the integral of the differential equation with respect to time to get $y't = -gt \implies y' = -g = -9.8$

But this is wrong

Comment: $\int y'' dt = y' + C$

Comment: The bullet won't get faster than its terminal velocity on the way down - probably around 90 m/s. The "window dressing" of this question ("During Cinco de Mayo...") actually confuses the intended mathematical exercise. The respondent is being asked to both use physical intuition and ignore it.

Comment: The bullet obeys $y'' = -g$, so it doesn't experience any air resistance (since it has no effect on it's acceleration), and therefore can not have a terminal velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y''(t) = -g$, then $y'(t) = y'(0) -gt$ and hence
$y(t) = y(0) +y'(0)t - {1 \over 2} g t^2$.

We want to solve $y(T) = y(0)$ (with $T>0$) to see when the bullet hits the ground.

This involves solving $y'(0)T = {1 \over 2} g T^2$, which gives
$T= { 2 y'(0) \over g}$.

Substituting into the equation for $y'$ gives
$y'(T) = y'(0) - g T = - y'(0)$.

A physics based approach will give the magnitude easily assuming that the bullet returns to the starting height.

Let $E(x,v) = gx+{1 \over 2} v^2$ and
consider $\phi(t) = E(y(t),y'(t))$. Differentiating shows that $\phi'(t) = 0$ and so $\phi$ is constant on a trajectory.

Hence if $y(T) = y(0)$, then $\phi(0) = g y(0) + {1 \over 2} y'(0)^2 = \phi(T)=g y(T) + {1 \over 2} y'(T)^2$, which yields $|y'(0)| = |y'(T)|$.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation only takes gravity into account, not air resistance, so physically speaking it's obvious that the bullet's speed at landing is the same as that with which it was fired.

But if you want to compute, notice that if you integrate $y''(t)$ you get $y'(t)$, not $y'(t) \cdot t$. And don't forget the constant of integration!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by physics methods.  The differential equation has no term with $y'$, so it is describing motion without air resistance.  So the kinetic energy of the bullet when it returns to its starting point is the same as when it started, therefore the velocity is the same as when it started, except obviously in the opposite direction.

Your attempt is wrong for two reasons.

1. The integral of $y''$ is not $y't$, it is $y'$.
2. The integral of $-g$ is not $-gt$, it is $-gt+C$ where $C$ is a constant.

See if you can fix these and complete the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way to do this would be to do it directly by calculus. You want the velocity at the ground, ie: you know that the change in it's y-position will be zero. Hence you can just do this directly with a single step of integration. Note that we can rewrite $y''={ d^2y \over dt^2}$ as:

$$ {d^2y\over dt^2} = {dv \over dt}={dv \over dt}{dy \over dy} = {dv \over dy}{dy \over dt}=v{dv\over dy}$$

Then we can attack your question directly

$$ v{dv\over dy} = -g $$

Multiplying by dy and integrating both sides gives:

$$ \int_{v_i}^{v_f} v dv = -g\int_{y_i}^{y_f} dy $$

Now note that since the ball is landing at the same height $y_i = y_f$, and therefore the right hand side of this equation will equate to zero. So we just need to evaluate the left hand side:

$$ {v_f^2\over 2 }-{v_i^2\over 2 }=0$$

This gives us a simple expression that:

$$ \left| v_i \right| = \left| v_f \right| $$

Hence, your ball will be going down at the same velocity it came up with. So:

$$ v_i = v_f $$